# Create a null-safe BooleanBinding with JavaFX 8

Tags: java, javafx, binding, javafx-8

I need help creating a `null`-safe `BooleanBinding`. It has to be `null`-safe since I can not provide default values for all attributes in the model (one reason: the model contains enumerations). My first approach has been as follows:

```
    executeButtonDisabled.bind(missionProperty().isNotNull().and(missionProperty().get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(MissionStatus.CREATED)));
    final BooleanBinding isNotExecutingBinding = missionProperty().isNotNull().and(missionProperty().get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(MissionStatus.EXECUTING));
    completeButtonDisabled.bind(isNotExecutingBinding);
    cancelButtonDisabled.bind(isNotExecutingBinding)
```

But that approach does not work because the complete expression is evaluated which results in a `NullPointerException` (but it correctly updates the buttons, when a property is provided). Now I am trying to use the `Bindings` class as suggested in [JavaFX binding and null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937258/javafx-binding-and-null-values), but I can't make it work. Here's my current approach:

```
    final BooleanBinding isNotCreatedBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
            () -> mission.isNull().getValue()
                    ? true
                    : missionProperty().get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(MissionStatus.CREATED).getValue());
    final BooleanBinding isNotExecutingBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
            () -> mission.isNull().getValue()
                    ? true
                    : missionProperty().get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(MissionStatus.EXECUTING).getValue());

    executeButtonDisabled.bind(isNotCreatedBinding);
    completeButtonDisabled.bind(isNotExecutingBinding);
    cancelButtonDisabled.bind(isNotExecutingBinding);
```

But this does not work and I do not understand why. It seems that the property binding for `modelProperty()` does not work here! Can you explain to me how-to convert the first working solution (at least without `null`) to a proper `null`-safe solution?

**Edit 2016-04-26:** The suggested solution does not work, therefore I created a simple fully-working example:

`Mission.java`:

```
package de.florianwolters.example.javafx.bindings;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Mission {

    enum Status {
        CREATED,
        EXECUTING,
        COMPLETED,
        CANCELED;
    }

    private final StringProperty shortName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final ObjectProperty<Status> status = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public Mission(final String shortName) {
        this.setShortName(shortName);
        this.setStatus(Status.CREATED);
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortNameProperty().get();
    }

    public void setShortName(final String shortName) {
        shortNameProperty().set(shortName);
    }

    public StringProperty shortNameProperty() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return statusProperty().get();
    }

    public void setStatus(final Status status) {
        statusProperty().set(status);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Status> statusProperty() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

`MissionDetailsViewModel.java`:

```
package de.florianwolters.example.javafx.bindings;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public final class MissionDetailsViewModel {

    /**
     * The logger used for logging in the `MissionDetailsViewModel` class.
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
        MissionDetailsViewModel.class);

    private ObjectProperty<Mission> mission = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper executeButtonDisabled = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(true);

    private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper completeButtonDisabled = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(true);

    private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper cancelButtonDisabled = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(true);

    /**
     * Constructs a `MissionDetailsViewModel`.
     */
    public MissionDetailsViewModel(final ObjectProperty<Mission> mission) {
        this.mission.bind(mission);
//        partialWorkingBinding();
        notWorkingBinding();
    }

    private void notWorkingBinding() {
        final BooleanBinding isNotCreatedBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
            () -> missionProperty().isNull().get()
                ? true
                : missionProperty().get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(Mission.Status.CREATED).get(),
            missionProperty());

        final BooleanBinding isNotExecutingBinding = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
            () -> mission.isNull().get()
                ? true
                : missionProperty().get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(Mission.Status.EXECUTING).get(),
            missionProperty());

        executeButtonDisabled.bind(isNotCreatedBinding);
        completeButtonDisabled.bind(isNotExecutingBinding);
        cancelButtonDisabled.bind(isNotExecutingBinding);
    }

    private void partialWorkingBinding() {
        executeButtonDisabled.bind(missionProperty().isNotNull().and(missionProperty().get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(Mission.Status.CREATED)));
        final BooleanBinding isNotExecutingBinding = missionProperty().isNotNull().and(missionProperty().get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(Mission.Status.EXECUTING));
        completeButtonDisabled.bind(isNotExecutingBinding);
        cancelButtonDisabled.bind(isNotExecutingBinding);
    }

    public boolean isExecuteButtonDisabled() {
        return executeButtonDisabledProperty().get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty executeButtonDisabledProperty() {
        return executeButtonDisabled;
    }

    public boolean isCompleteButtonDisabled() {
        return completeButtonDisabledProperty().get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty completeButtonDisabledProperty() {
        return completeButtonDisabled;
    }

    public boolean isCancelButtonDisabled() {
        return cancelButtonDisabledProperty().get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty cancelButtonDisabledProperty() {
        return cancelButtonDisabled;
    }

    public Mission getMission() {
        return missionProperty().get();
    }

    public void setMission(final Mission mission) {
        missionProperty().set(mission);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Mission> missionProperty() {
        return mission;
    }
}
```

`MissionDetailsViewModelTest.java`:

```
package de.florianwolters.example.javafx.bindings;

import static eu.lestard.assertj.javafx.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public final class MissionDetailsViewModelTest {
    private Mission mission;
    private MissionDetailsViewModel viewModel;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
        mission = new Mission("My Short Name");
    viewModel = new MissionDetailsViewModel(new SimpleObjectProperty<Mission>(mission));
  }

  @Test
  public void testInitialValues() {
        assertThat(viewModel.executeButtonDisabledProperty()).isFalse();
        assertThat(viewModel.completeButtonDisabledProperty()).isTrue();
        assertThat(viewModel.cancelButtonDisabledProperty()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
  public void testMissionStatusSetToExecuting() {
        mission.setStatus(Mission.Status.EXECUTING);
        assertThat(viewModel.executeButtonDisabledProperty()).isTrue();
        assertThat(viewModel.completeButtonDisabledProperty()).isFalse();
        assertThat(viewModel.cancelButtonDisabledProperty()).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
  public void testMissionStatusSetToCompleted() {
        mission.setStatus(Mission.Status.COMPLETED);
        assertThat(viewModel.executeButtonDisabledProperty()).isTrue();
        assertThat(viewModel.completeButtonDisabledProperty()).isTrue();
        assertThat(viewModel.cancelButtonDisabledProperty()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
  public void testMissionStatusSetToCanceled() {
        mission.setStatus(Mission.Status.CANCELED);
        assertThat(viewModel.executeButtonDisabledProperty()).isTrue();
        assertThat(viewModel.completeButtonDisabledProperty()).isTrue();
        assertThat(viewModel.cancelButtonDisabledProperty()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

The unit test fails with the code above (the method `notWorkingBinding()` is used) but works with the method `partialWorkingBinding()`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set up the calculation function for `isNotCreatedBinding`, but you didn't set the dependencies for the binding. You need to add `mision` as dependency:

```
 Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
        () -> mission.isNull().getValue()
                ? true
                : missionProperty().get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(MissionStatus.CREATED).getValue(), mission);
```

**EDIT**

You need to listen to the statusProperty instead of missionProperty, which will not work with `createBooleanBinding` when missionProperty().get() == null.

<strike>But you can use a `When` binding:</strike>

(is causing a `NullPointerException` as already mentioned in the question)

```
   BooleanBinding isNotCreatedBinding = new When(mission.isNotNull()).then(mission.get().statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(Mission.Status.CREATED)).otherwise(false);
```

Or a more low-level solution:

```
 missionProperty().addListener((ov, m, m1) -> {
            if (m1 != null) {
                executeButtonDisabled.bind(m1.statusProperty().isNotEqualTo(Mission.Status.CREATED));
            }else {
                executeButtonDisabled.unbind();
                executeButtonDisabled.set(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work, refer to my updated question. I provided a full example containing a unit test.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get a `NullPointerException` with the `When` binding. This is driving me crazy, I think this is a very common use case. Think about a selection in a master view (e.g. `ListView`) that is initially set to `null`. I bind the `mission` in the detail view to the selection in the master view, but I cannot make it work...

Comment: Ok, got the NPE as well... Good to know that `When` is not working as expected (I should have paid more attention to the links). Seems the difficult part is to keep track of changes of both, mission and status. Maybe you can change the design of your classes, or try the low-level solution I've added

Comment: The `ChangeListener` solution did the job. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Florian "driving me crazy" ... This tripped me up a few times. I used a ChangeListener to achieve the desired result, but just now decided to see if anyone else was having the same problem. And then ... I read the Javadoc. It says, "then(final boolean thenValue)" -> "Defines a constant value...."  It's not an expression which is evaluated later as the value of the dependency changes, rather it's the value at the time you are creating the When binding. In your case, you haven't initialized the value of missionProperty so that "missionProperty.get() is null at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Tomas Mikula's [ReactFX framework (v 2.0)](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX/releases/tag/v2.0-M2) has this functionality built in:

```
import org.reactfx.value.Val;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class NestedBindingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BooleanProperty disable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        disable.addListener((obs, wasDisabled, isNowDisabled) -> 
            System.out.println("disable: "+wasDisabled+" -> "+isNowDisabled));

        ObjectProperty<Item> item = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        Val<Item.Status> status = Val.flatMap(item, Item::statusProperty);
        disable.bind(status.map(s -> s == Item.Status.PENDING).orElseConst(true));

        Item i = new Item();
        System.out.println("Setting item");
        item.set(i);

        System.out.println("Setting item status to PENDING");
        i.setStatus(Item.Status.PENDING);

        System.out.println("Setting item status to READY");
        i.setStatus(Item.Status.READY);

        System.out.println("Setting item to null");
        item.set(null);
    }

    public static class Item {
        public enum Status {PENDING, READY}

        private final ObjectProperty<Status> status = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public final ObjectProperty<Status> statusProperty() {
            return this.status;
        }


        public final NestedBindingTest.Item.Status getStatus() {
            return this.statusProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setStatus(final NestedBindingTest.Item.Status status) {
            this.statusProperty().set(status);
        }



    }
}
```