# Bind to null / not null in JavaFX?

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, javafx-8

Sorry can't find is it possible to bind `JavaFX` property to `boolean` result of checking some other property being `null` or not `null`.

Don't see why this can be prohibited.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866346/create-a-null-safe-booleanbinding-with-javafx-8/36867491#36867491

Answer (score 4):

You could try creating a BooleanBinding

```
BooleanBinding isPropertyNull = Bindings.isNull(otherProperty);
```

or use Bindings

```
Bindings.when(otherPropertyIsNull)
        .then(true)
        .otherwise(false);
```

If you could expand on what you're trying to do I might be able to edit the above to suit